# The log rotation strategy is not working as expected？

Tags: log4j2

everyone:

My purpose：When the log file

reaches midnight every day, triggering log rotation and compressing it into the specified date folder.

such examples：the log file app_normal.log generated at 2023-12-07，need rollover to 2023-12-07/app_normal_2023-12-07_1.log.zip

However, I find  the log file is rotated to 2023-12-08/app_normal_2023-12-08_1.log.zip，but this is not what I expected!

If I rewrite DefaultRolloverStrategy by myself and set formatFileName useCurrentTime true ，the log file is rotated as what i expected.

```
<RollingFile name="app" fileName="${FILE_PATH}/app_normal.log" filePattern="${FILE_PATH}/app_normal_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.log.gz">
  <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
  <Policies>
    <CronTriggerStrategy schedule="0 0 0 * * * ?"/>
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="nomax" compressionLevel="5"/>
</RollingFile>
```

My Question: Why log4j2 set formatFileName  useCurrentTime false in DefaultRolloverStrategy ?  Can developers set this attribute in the future?